# Unable to use wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I used this command to install python in ubuntu 15.10

```
"sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8"
```

When I write "import wx",
This error appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
from wx._core import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
import _core_
ImportError: No module named _core_
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that path should read `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx` so I would uninstall and try again. Also, you don't mention your operating system, which might be relevant.

Comment: i tried reinstallation but same error

Comment: Try installing it with Synaptic instead. I think that's how I've installed wxPython on Ubuntu variants

Comment: i tried that too but same error. I also installed wxglade , but then also same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned in my comment the wx package should be loaded into:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx
rather than /usr/local.
So check where on your system it actually is e.g.
`sudo find / -name _core_.so -print`

Check your python version

```
$ python                                                          
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Then check your PYTHONPATH environment variable to make sure that it isn't messing things up. i.e. echo $PYTHONPATH
Adjusting that will depend on your shell, edit .bashrc or .profile , wherever the shell you are using sets up its environment.
Installing wx is usually done with synaptic but you can use apt or pip as well.
My gut feel, is that your $PYTHONPATH is messing things up.
Personally I run with no $PYTHONPATH at all.

Edit:
You can do a quick test with the following:

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

which will remove PYTHONPATH, then try importing wx,
if it works and you are using the bash shell

```
$ env | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

edit the .bashrc file in your $HOME directory and for now, comment out the lines that define the PYTHONPATH, log back in again and try again.
If you are using another shell the file that contains the environment variables will differ, csh is .cshrc and ksh will be .profile.
Ultimately once you have this working, it will still be worthwhile to try to identify why the PYTHONPATH was set in the first place and what set it.

Comment: Reinstallation didn't help.